# Python input function explanation

Tags: python, numpy, input

Could someone explain the role of the following functions:

```
list()
map()
split()
```

In the context of this line of code please:

```
input = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Finally, should it be:

```
int,input()
```

rather than:

```
int(input())
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list

Comment: Don't use `input` as a variable name (i.e. `input = ...`). It's a built-in function, and you just replaced it with a list, so you can't use that function again later in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input().split()` takes a line of keyboard input from the user and returns a list of words (separated by spaces).  For example if the user typed `the quick brown fox`, it would return `['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']`.

`map()` takes a function and a sequence of values, calls the function on each value in the sequence, and returns a sequence of all the results.  For example `map(int, ['1', '2', '3'])` would return `[1, 2, 3]`.

Finally, `list()` takes a sequence of values and returns it as a list.

So overall, your example line of code accepts a string of input from the user, splits it into a list of words, calls `int()` on each word, and assembles a final list of the returned values.

To answer your question about `int`, yes, in this case that is the correct way to call it.  `map()` takes a function *object*; you're not actually calling `int()` yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Definitely cleared that up allot. So the default 'split' is ' '. So  `input = list(map(int,input().split(' ')))`, would compile in the same as as the line in the question?

Answer (score 2):

All of these functions are members of the standard library and are as such covered by the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html).

That being said, I'll summarise them briefly.

1. `list` turns an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html?highlight=iterable) into a list. In this case, the iterable is a `map` object.
2. `map` takes a function `f` (or any callable, really), and an iterable `iter` and produces another iterable where the callable is applied to each element in `iter`.

   In your case, the callable is `int`, which tries to convert its argument to an integer. `map` is a common term for applying a function to a collection of elements, but the 'Pythonic' way is to use a list comprehension:

   ```
    [f(x) for x in iterable] == list(map(f, iterable))
   ```
3. `split` is a method on `str`ing objects, which divides the given string at every occurrence of the given separator, returning a list. If the separator argument is omitted, it defaults to a space.

---

Putting it all together, you're reading input from stdin, splitting the resulting string into multiple strings, mapping `int` to each item (turning them into integers, or causing an exception on input like `'words instead of numbers'`) and converting the mapping to a list.

You're then shadowing a built in by assigning the result to `input`, which is generally speaking a bad idea (imagine the confusion when `input()` causes an error).

To answer your second question: no, since `map` takes two separate arguments.

---

I'd rewrite it slightly, if I were using it in a production environment:

```
try:
  numbers = [int(n) for n in input('Space-separated integers, please: ').split()]
except ValueError as e:
  print('I needed numbers. You gave me something else.')
```

The argument to `input` is a prompt to the user (it's optional, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down
`input = list(map(int,input().split()))`

`map(int, input().split())` calls the `int()` functions which returns an int for every object returned from `input().split()`

Now `map` returns a list object in Python 2.7 and a map object in Python 3. If you're running 2.7 then the `list(..)` is useless. In 3 it is required.

Regarding your second question, `map()` takes two arguments, so it needs to be `int, input()` because `int(input())` is considered a single arg.

`input = list(map(int,input().split()))`

Comment: I checked with 2.7, thanks for the comment. I edited my answer

Comment: If it was python 2.7, you should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help, folks!